# Разрешение типов unsigned char * и char *

Tags: c, char

Имеется следующий код.

```
unsigned char var;

...

var = (unsigned char)fgetc(stream);
func(&var);


void func(char *data)
{
   char *tmp;
   int i;

   tmp = data;
   ...
}
```

Отлаживая в `gdb`, у отладчика не возникает здесь никаких проблем. В VS же подчёркивает `func(&var)` и пишет:

> аргумент типа "unsigned char *" несовместим с параметром типа "char
>   *"

Собственно, `unsigned char` необходим, по скольку считываются ASCII символы текста. Вопрос такой: почему `gdb` пропускает это, а VS - нет?

Comment: Как ни странно, но `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char` - это разные типы... Но поясните мне, как у вас такое работает вообще? Может, не `fgets`, а `fgetc`? И зачем вам `unsigned char`, если `fgetc` будет отлично работать с `char`?

Comment: во-первых, gdb — это отладчи, ему всё равно... подозреваю, что ты имеешь ввиду gcc. Во-вторых, `fgets` вызывается абсолютно не так, в остальном с точки зрения Си код корректный, хотя и абсурдный, может VS пытается компилировать его как C++?

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо за замечание: у меня опечатка - там действительно fgetc.
Во-вторых, в makefile прописан gcc, так что видит как си.

Comment: VC выдает - при компиляции **в режиме С** предупреждение - *test.c(18): warning C4057: функция: "char *" отличается от "unsigned char *" по косвенному обращению к слегка разным базовым типам*, **в режиме С++** - ошибку *test.cpp(18): error C2664: "void func(char *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "unsigned char *" в "char *"
note: Типы, на которые указывают указатели, не связаны; для преобразования требуется reinterpret_cast, приведение в стиле С или приведение в стиле функции*

Comment: @Harry, хм...Я в VS создавал проект Console App C++, хоть и создал файл с расширением .c. Можно как-то заставить VS воспринимать мой код как Сишный?

Comment: Конечно, можно - только где именно в настройках проекта искать - не помню. Но соответствующие ключи командной строки /Tc и /Tp

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. В свойствах проекта ->c/c++ -> дополнительно -> компилировать как. Там выбрать как код С (/TC)

Comment: Вообще-то, `fgetc` возвращает `int`. Может стоит учесть этот факт и переделать под него остальные части программы?

Comment: @Setplus: Попытка неявного преобразования между `char *` и `unsigned char *` является ошибкой в совершенно одинаковой степени и в С, и в С++. То, что некоторые компиляторы С традиционно рапортуют эту ошибку как "предупреждение" на самом деле ничего не значит.

Comment: @AnT Си не делает различий между явным и неявным преобразованием, т.е. все преобразования, которые разрешены явно также разрешены и неявно. Преобразование одного указателя в указатель на другой тип, также прямо разрешены (если оба они корректно выровнены, иначе — UB).

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Абсолютно неверно. Ни в коем случае. Язык С некогда не делает неявных преобразований для несвязанных между собой типов указателей. Такие преобразования **прямо запрещены**. Чтобы развеять странное верование в возможность таких неявных преобразований, в стандарт С99 даже специально добавили открытым текстом: "6.5.4/3 Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified **by means of an explicit cast**".

Comment: Необходимости в этом добавлении не было (С89/90 и так запрещал такие неявные преобразования), но глупая легенда о том, что в С можно неявно преобразовывать любые указатели к любым просто всех достала. С более общей точки зрения, откуда вы взяли, что "Си не делает различий между явным и неявным преобразованием" мне не ясно. Различие между явными и неявными преобразованиями в С присутствует в полной мере, нечем не отличаясь по сути от С++.

Comment: @AnT, соглашусь, был не прав...